# Advanced Magmi value replacer problem

Tags: magmi

I have a CSV which I want to use for import. It has clomuns with compatibility information as follows:

```
|  |Compatible with Product X|Compatible with Product Y|Compatible with Product Z|
|1 |      Y                  |                         |       Y                 |
|2 |                         |       Y                 |       Y                 |
|3 |      Y                  |       Y                 |                         |
|4 |                         |                         |                         |
```

I want to use value replacer to map the colums to the my Magento attribute "compatibilty" which is a multiselect box.

The value of the "compatibilty" attribute should be as follows for a single value

```
Product X
```

And for multiple values it should be like this

```
Product X;Product Y;Product Z
```

I first use the column mapper to map every different cloum to campatibility. Then I use value replacer on the compatibility column. I came up with the following code the make it possible to assign the right values to the right products:

```
{{ {item.'Product_X}=='Y'?'Product X;':NULL }}{{ {item.'Product_Y}=='Y'?'Product Y;':NULL }}{{ {item.'Product_Z}=='Y'?'Product Z;':NULL }}

Or better readable

{{ {item.'Product_X}=='Y'?'Product X;':NULL }}
{{ {item.'Product_Y}=='Y'?'Product Y;':NULL }}
{{ {item.'Product_Z}=='Y'?'Product Z;':NULL }}
```

Everything gets set correctly. But the problem is that Magmi sometimes adds an ampty value to the attribute and assigns it to a product. I obviously don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a formula that does what you expect (since Magmi value replacer only accepts R-values)

It's a bit complicated, so maybe developing a very simple plugin maybe more readable.

```
implode(';',array_filter(array({item.Product_X}=='Y'?'Product X':'',{item.Product_Y}=='Y'?'Product Y':'',{item.Product_Z}=='Y'?'Product Z':'')))
```

it also trims the end ; if any.

Comment: I see what you are doing. I didn't know I could use any PHP in the value replacer. Can I just use all off your code in the value replacer? I did think to write a plugin for it but I don't know where to start. Do you know any good resources for that?

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with R-Values?

Comment: a Rvalue is a value that is assignable to a variable.
ie : $x=<this is a rvalue>

Comment: Thanks. The code doesn't work out of the box. I removed the ending semicolon to make it executable. But, the problem is it still adds empty values to the attribute in Magento. I thought It might be a problem with several semicolons after eachother. The example I gave is simplified for obvious reasons. In reality there are 12 columns with compatibility info. So what i did is I replaced the first paramater of the str_replace function with an array which has ';;', ';;;', ';;;;' etc. up to 12. It still adds emppty values to the attibute. Any ideas? Is there a way to do a debug view or so?

Comment: updated code to remove empty values (added array_filter , removed trim & str_replace since array would then contain only non empty values)

Comment: As far as I have tested now it works, thanks! It would be very convenient if there was a debug mode to see the output after it was parsed by the value replacer.

Answer (score 0):

It will add an empty value because of the trailing ';' that will always be prevalent if any of the columns have 'Y' in them. The empty space after the ';' will represent an empty value.

It is akin to doing this,

```
$myVar = '';
$myVar .= 'Product X;';
$myVar .= 'Product Y;';

// Product X;Product Y;   (<- empty value here!)
```

Instead of this:

```
$myVar = array();
$myVar[] = 'Product X';
$myVar[] = 'Product Y';
$myVarString = implode(';', $myVar);
// Product X;Product Y
```

You need to do the latter, if Magmi's value mapper will allow it. As this will remove any trailing ';'.

Comment: Can I use (any) PHP in the value replacer?